# Make parent divs height match the child height issue

Tags: css

Trying to make the parent divs height to match it's containing child-div.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        Content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Heres my css:

```
#parent {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #f3efe7;
    z-index: 1;
    position:relative;
    top: 100px; // I have a header that is 100px in height and set to position: fixed.
}

    #child {
        max-width: 920px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height:140%;
    }
```

The child content is cropped and not fully displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards Johan

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/AKyYL/

Comment: agree, it works http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: //this is not a css comment --> CSS always and only:  /* this is a css comment */

Comment: Yepp it works. I found out that it's my footer that's making the mess. I have updated the post with that css. And yes I know how comments in CSS should like.. I was lazy on that part ;)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Found out that it's my footer makeing the problem... since it overlays ontop and part of the overlaying content. Where is the problem in that footer CSS? I just can't understand whats making the problem...

```
Here's the CSS for that:

#footer-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background: #ffffff url('images/header/test4.svg') no-repeat; 
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f3efe7;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```